# DataFrame - вычисление смещения внутри окна до ближайщего Min/Max элемента

Tags: python, pandas

Как в DataFrame вычислить смещения внутри окна от текущего элемента до ближайщего Min/Max элемента?

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([1,20,3,40,5,60,12,11,12,4], columns=['close'])

print(df)
print(df.rolling(window=3).max())
```

Желаемый результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть для каждого элемента a[i] вы желаете найти i - j, где j = index_of_max_in_window(array, i, window_length)? Ну и соответственно то же самое для минимума.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
df["offset"] = df.rolling(window=3).apply(pd.Series.idxmax)
df["offset"] = df.index - df["offset"]
```

тогда df будет:

```
   close  offset
0      1     NaN
1     20     NaN
2      3     1.0
3     40     0.0
4      5     1.0
5     60     0.0
6     12     1.0
7     11     2.0
8     12     2.0
9      4     1.0
```

То же самое и с `idxmin`. Обратите, кстати, внимание на значение смещения в 8-м ряду: оно равно 2, а не 0, поскольку `idxmax`/`idxmin` ищут первый в серии максимум/минимум.

**UPDATE**

Если нужно, чтобы поиск максимума/минимума велся с конца окна, можно сделать так:

```
def find_peak(window):
    res=pd.Series(window)[::-1].idxmax()
    return res

df["offset"] = df.rolling(window=3).apply(find_peak)
df["offset"] = df.index - df["offset"]
```

тогда `df` будет:

```
   close  offset
0      1     NaN
1     20     NaN
2      3     1.0
3     40     0.0
4      5     1.0
5     60     0.0
6     12     1.0
7     11     2.0
8     12     0.0
9      4     1.0
```

Comment: Уточнить хочу по 8 ряду. То есть поиск ведется с первого элемента окна, а 0 элемент окна не участвует в поиске. Верно? В этом случае 5 и 3 строчки тоже не верны

Comment: Не так. у вас окно из трех строк. 0,1, 2. 3я и 5я строки верны, потому что для них смещение до первого максимума в окне - 0. в а восьмой строке смещение до первого максимума - 2.

Comment: Как можно добиться, чтобы смещение внутри окна считалось снизу вверх, а не сверх вниз? Оффсет для 8 строки должен быть 0, а не 2.

Comment: Я анализирую изменения цены по историческим данным. Мне нужно вычислить смещение когда был ближайщий хай и лоу по отношению к текущему времени (свече) в обратном порядке . смещение +3 означает, что ближащий пик был четвертой свечой по отношению к текущей. отсчет идет от текущей свечи и в обратную сторону.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Я обновил ответ